# Can an Activity be started from within a WidgetAppProvider?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget that I have an intent that starts an activity when I click, but I need to get saved Data into the widget, so onEnabled can I start an Activity that will look up the saved data for the activity?

Also an intent I need to set up for the click events... how do I set these up with out first having the config show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still do not know if an activity can be explicitly started without doing something like an onclickevent... but saving data within the widget can be accomplished by using the

```
Context.getSharedPreferences( String name, int mode );
```

to get saved prefernces, and by using

```
    nt[] allids = AppWidgetManager .getInstance(context) .
getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, AwarenessWidget.class));
```

to get all the IDS